Shifting the overlaping pgfplot axis labels
I'm struggling to find a way to make the plot look the same as source image. In it, on the x axis, the "close" (65,67 and 122,124) labels are shifted. I cannot force the pgfplot to do something similar. Is it somehow possible to define multiple sets of extra x ticks or something different?
Edit: I care about the x axis only and it's labels in pgfplots, not the source picture as whole.
Source image:

My attempt by "hack-ish" shift:

Current latex souce:
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
  xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
  yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
}
\pgfplotsset{ 
    every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
    every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-},
}

\definecolor{c1}{RGB}{0,147,132}
\definecolor{c2}{RGB}{102,102,102}

\definecolor{themeBlue}{RGB}{1, 103, 143}
\definecolor{themeOrange}{RGB}{221, 109, 16}
\definecolor{themeTeal}{RGB}{18, 54, 69}
\definecolor{themeGrey}{RGB}{120, 121, 124}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,datavisualization, arrows.meta}

\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \begin{axis} [
         mark size=1.0pt,
         axis x line  = top,
         width        = 1\textwidth,
         height       = .7\textwidth,
         ymax         = 10,
         ymin         = 0,
         ytick        = \empty,
         y dir        = reverse,
         xmax         = 199,
         xmin         = 0,
         xtick        = {0,14,37,53,65,98,122,183,199},
         extra x ticks = {67, 124},
         extra x tick style={
            xticklabel style={anchor=south, yshift=-1.5ex, xshift=1.5ex}
         },
         xmajorgrids,
         grid style=dashed,
         x tick label style = {
            font=\sffamily\scriptsize,
            rotate=45,
            anchor=south
         },
         execute at begin axis = {
            \draw[thick] (rel axis cs:0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,0);
         },
       ]

      \foreach \x [count=\y from 1, remember=\x as \lastx (initially 65)] in {124, 14, 122, 37, 183, 98, 53} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\realy}{9 - \y};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lasty}{\realy - 1};
        \addplot[color=themeOrange, thick, mark=*, arrows = {Latex[color=themeOrange!50,scale=.8]-}] coordinates {
            (\lastx, \realy)
            (\x, \lasty)
          };
      }
      \addplot[color=themeOrange, thick, arrows = {-Latex[color=themeOrange!50,scale=.8, ]}] coordinates {
        (65, 8)
        (67, 9)
      };
    \end{axis}
   
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Here is a way to do it by Tikz, just like an artist would do a one-time drawing. Let's go through important steps.
Scaling
No scaling is provided. Rather the x-values are interpreted as being in mm. If you want to scale, use library calc.
Frame
Nothing exciting here. Define a style frm as needed. Size is as assumed to range from (0,0) to (19.9,-10).
Data
Assuming y-data simply go in integer steps from -1 to -9, and the foreach loop just has x-data in the order as they appear from top to bottom.
A nice way to dal with that would be using an xy-array. Though pgf provides that, code becomes complex while being straight forward quickly. So here's the trick, with pseudocodish coordinates:

first line: \draw (first) -- (second);
to iterate between the previous and the next data point we put a coordinate, which is constantly overwritten
so first line: \draw (first) -- (second) coordinate (A);
loop: \draw (A) -- (nextCoord) coordinate (A);
this way we can draw as many pathes as needed, where style lne just puts the right format (subpaths omit all the arrows in between)
finaly put dot-nodes (filled circles) where you want them

Ticks
Just loop and draw the ticks, where the x-values can appear in any order.
Kindly watch the extra coordinates (L1) ... (L9) set there to be reused with the labels.
x-labels

create 3 sets of data: regular (south), left (east) and right (west)
loop over a pair of data \foreach \i/\l  in {1/0, ...
this is similar to specifying data using the coordinates format there

Formats / styles
Introduce and refine them as you go. Also use them to make code easier to grasp (i.e. writing less characters per statement).

I put teal in lne to see easier what's going on; delete it to turn on black (default)
the lbl style show how to impact fonts (serif and bold)


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ self-defined formats ~
    frm/.style={fill=gray!10},          % frame
    >={Stealth},                        % all those arrow tips
    dot/.style={fill=black,circle,      % a node with a circle as shape
                inner sep=0,
                minimum width=8pt},
    lne/.style={line width=1.5pt,->,teal},  % connecting the data
    lbl/.style={font={\sffamily\bfseries}},
 ]
    % ~~~ the frame ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[frm] (0,0) rectangle (19.9,-10);
    
    % ~~~ curve ~~~~~~~
    \draw[lne] (5.3,-1) node[dot] {}    
            -- (9.8,-2) coordinate (A);
    \foreach 
        \x [count=\y] 
            in {18.3,3.7,12.2,1.4,12.4,6.5,6.7}
        \draw[lne] (A) node[dot] {} -- (\x,-\y-2) coordinate (A);

                
    % ~~~ ticks ~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,1.4,3.7,5.3,6.5,6.7,9.8,
                    12.2,12.4,18.3,19.9}    
        \draw   (\x,0) -- +(0,3mm) coordinate(L\i);

        
    % ~~~ regular labels ~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \i/\l 
        in {1/0, 2/14, 3/37, 4/53,  7/98, 10/183, 11/199}
        \node[anchor=south,lbl] at (L\i) {\l};      
    % ~~~ left labels ~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \i/\l 
        in {5/65, 8/122}    
        \node[anchor=south east,lbl] at (L\i) {\l};     
    % ~~~ right labels ~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \i/\l 
        in {6/67, 9/124}
        \node[anchor=south west,lbl] at (L\i) {\l};
                
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you for the solution using Tikz only! I had something similar as my first attempt, but Your's is much more polished and cool. In my question I wanted to ask more specifically about the pgfplots library and it's axis configurations and spacing of the labels on it. The look I provided is sufficient for me, only the axis looks "hideous". But I think I will overlay tikz drawn axis similar to yours with the pgfplot in order to latter provide data only and let it be drawn automatically.

Thank you. Your approach is also interesting, splitting data over several \addplots. However, your task is a bit unusual for pgfplots. It certainly can be done there too, with some twists and tweaking  here and there.
